# Código informando que método não existe mas método está na Classe

Tags: php

Tenho o **array** abaixo que vem de uma **consulta** à base de dados por um método de uma **classe**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Estudos Object
        (
            [idEstudo:Estudos:private] => 12
            [assunto:Estudos:private] => Teste
            [estudo:Estudos:private] => Testando...
            [data:Estudos:private] => 2019-01-28
            [dataEstudo:Estudos:private] => 0000-00-00
        )

    [1] => Estudos Object
        (
            [idEstudo:Estudos:private] => 13
            [assunto:Estudos:private] => Dia D
            [estudo:Estudos:private] => Dia de brincar
            [data:Estudos:private] => 2019-02-25
            [dataEstudo:Estudos:private] => 0000-00-00
        )

    [2] => Estudos Object
        (
            [idEstudo:Estudos:private] => 14
            [assunto:Estudos:private] => Perizes
            [estudo:Estudos:private] => Perdição total?
            [data:Estudos:private] => 2019-02-26
            [dataEstudo:Estudos:private] => 2019-02-26
        )

    [3] => Estudos Object
        (
            [idEstudo:Estudos:private] => 15
            [assunto:Estudos:private] => Estudo
            [estudo:Estudos:private] => Estudando...
            [data:Estudos:private] => 2019-02-26
            [dataEstudo:Estudos:private] => 2019-02-27
        )

    [4] => Estudos Object
        (
            [idEstudo:Estudos:private] => 16
            [assunto:Estudos:private] => Estudo de Células
            [estudo:Estudos:private] => Esse estudo vai bombar
            [data:Estudos:private] => 2019-04-12
            [dataEstudo:Estudos:private] => 2019-04-12
        )

)
```

A **classe** responsável por esses **objetos** é a seguinte:

```
<?php

class Estudos {

    private $idEstudo; 
    private $assunto; 
    private $estudo; 
    private $data; 
    private $dataEstudo; 

    public function __construct($_assunto, $_estudo, $_data, $_dataEstudo) {

        $this->assunto = $_assunto;
        $this->estudo = $_estudo;
        $this->data = $_data;
        $this->dataEstudo = $_dataEstudo;

    }


    public function setIdEstudo ($_idEstudo) {

        $this->idEstudo = $_idEstudo;

    }


    public function getIdEstudo () {

        return $this->idEstudo;

    }


    public function getAssunto () {

        return $this->assunto;

    }


    public function getEstudo () {

        return $this->estudo;

    }

    public function getData () {

        return $this->data;

    }

    public function getDataEstudo () {

        return $this->dataEstudo;

    }

}


?>
```

Esse **array** de **objetos** dessa **classe** vem desse **método**:

```
public
function listar( $estudosDao, $phpUtil ) {

    $estudos = $estudosDao->pesquisaEstudos();

    $lista = null;

    if ( $estudos != null ) {

        $lista = "<h1 class='hCentralizado'>Listagem de Estudos</h1>";

        $lista .= "

            <ul class=listaTopo id=listaTopo>
                   <li style='width: 20%;'>Data do Estudo</li><!--
                   <li style='width: 25%;'>Assunto</li><!--
                --><li style='width: 25%;'>Estudo</li><!--
                --><li style='width: 15%;'>Editar</li><!--
                --><li style='width: 15%;'>Excluir</li>
            </ul>

        ";

        $pagina = isset( $_GET[ "pagina" ] ) ? $_GET[ "pagina" ] : 1;

        $regTotal = count( $estudos );
        $regPagina = 5;
        $limite = ceil( $regTotal / $regPagina );
        $inicio = ( $pagina * $limite ) - $limite;
        $fim = ( $pagina * $limite );


        $limitacao = "LIMIT " . $inicio . "," . $fim;
        $estudosPag = $estudosDao->pesquisaEstudos( $limitacao );

        $contador = 0;

        foreach ( $estudosPag as $estudo ) {

            $backGround = $contador % 2 == 0 ? "#CCC" : "#GGG";

            $linkPagina = isset( $_GET[ "pagina" ] ) ? "&pagina=" . $_GET[ "pagina" ] : "";

            $assunto = strlen( $estudo->getAssunto() ) >= 20 ? substr( $estudo->getAssunto(), 0, 20 ) . "...": $estudo->getAssunto();
            $estudo = strlen( $estudo->getEstudo() ) >= 20 ? substr( $estudo->getEstudo(), 0, 20 ) . "...": $estudo->getEstudo();
            $dataEstudo = $phpUtil->formataData( $estudo->getDataEstudo());

            $iconeVer     = "<img src='_imgs/editar.png'>";             
            $linkVer      = "<a href='?editarEstudos&form&idEstudo=" . $estudo->getIdEstudo(). "'>" . $iconeVer . "</a>";       

            $iconeExcluir = "<img src='_imgs/excluir.png' style='width: 40px;'>";
            $linkExclui = "<a href='?editarEstudos&excluir" . $linkPagina . "&idEstudo=" . $estudo->getIdEstudo() . "'>" . $iconeExcluir . "</a>";

            $lista .= "

                <ul class=listaRegistros style='background-color:" . $backGround . "'>
                       <li style='width: 20%'>" . $dataEstudo . "</li><!--
                    --><li style='width: 25%'>" . $assunto . "</li><!--
                    --><li style='width: 25%'>" . $estudo . "</li><!--
                    --><li style='width: 15%'>" . $linkVer . "</li><!--
                    --><li style='width: 15%'>" . $linkExclui . "</li>
                </ul>

            ";

            $contador++;

        }

        $pa = $pagina - 1;
        $pp = $pagina + 1;

        if ( $pagina == 1 ) {

            $anterior = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=" . $limite . "'>Anterior</a>";
            $proximo = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=" . $pp . "'>Próxima</a>";

        }

        if ( $pagina > 1 ) {

            $anterior = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=" . $pa . "'>Anterior</a>";
            $proximo = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=" . $pp . "'>Próxima</a>";

        }

        if ( $pagina == $limite ) {

            $pa = $limite == 1 ? 1 : $pa;

            $anterior = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=" . $pa . "'>Anterior</a>";
            $proximo = "<a href='?editarEstudos&listar&pagina=1'>Próxima</a>";

        }

        $botoes = "<div class=hCentralizado style='width: 200px;'>" . $anterior . "  // " . $proximo . "</div>";

        $lista .= $limite == 1 ? "" : $botoes;        

    }

    return $lista;

}
```

Esse é o **erro** que estou obtendo:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDataEstudo() on string in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\_classes\_mvc\_vistas\EstudosVistas.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\admin\_editar\estudo.php(7): EstudosVistas-&gt;listar(Object(EstudosDao), Object(PhpUtil))
#1 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\adminConteudo.php(202): require_once('D:\\Trabalhos\\ho...')
#2 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\admin.php(71): require_once('D:\\Trabalhos\\ho...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\_classes\_mvc\_vistas\EstudosVistas.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
```

O **erro**, conforme entendi a mensagem, está dizendo que a **classe** não possui os **métodos** abaixo:

```
$estudo->getIdEstudo()
$estudo->getDataEstudo()
```

Mas a **classe** possui sim estes **métodos**.

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Linhas antes você fez `$estudo = strlen(...)`, o que sobrescreve o seu objeto original por uma *string*.

Comment: nesse caso estou entregando essa mudança apenas uma variável. Essa mudança é perpetua? Se sim., O que posso fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Não, mas será *string* até o final do laço e você tentou acessar métodos do objeto quando ele já era uma *string*. O que pode fazer é definir nomes diferentes para evitar o conflito.

Comment: entendi agora criei uma variável com o mesmo nome do objeto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa linha você está transformando o `$estudo` em uma string:

```
$estudo = strlen( $estudo->getEstudo() ) >= 20 ? substr( $estudo->getEstudo(), 0, 20 ) . "...": $estudo->getEstudo();
```

Por isso está dando o erro pois não não existe está função em uma string, utilize outro nome de variável.

Comment: verdade essa variável não deveria ter esse nome que já é o nome dos objetos. Era isso mesmo!